# EPUB3 Reader Development?

Tags: epub3

I need to know about **EPUB3 Reader Development**. I Am using readium to develop epub3. Looks as if http://readium.org/ offers exactly what I am looking for; but I only find descriptions for the integration of Readium into different browsers.
**I want to use Readium as a epub-reader within my content; does anyone know, how to do that?**

Can you please suggest me what to do ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want to use Readium as a epub-reader within my content"? Do you mean from within your app? Within your website?

Comment: Within my app.@AlexMilewski

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the Readium SDK: http://readium.org/projects/readium-sdk.

It is currently in development and therefore may or may not be useful to you at this stage... Most of the stuff is fairly stable, and developement is ongoing. You can find the SDK code here: https://github.com/readium/readium-sdk, and the different launcher repos here: https://github.com/readium/.

Good luck!